How to avoid the joblib's parallel open many files?
EDIT: I have submit a issue on github, in that version I remove the user limit in lsof, and the opened files are much more.
A simplified case as following(Python 3.11.8, joblib 1.4.0):
## lsof.py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import time
import sys

def f():
    time.sleep(5)
    return 1.0

def get_num_of_opened_files() -> int:
    from subprocess import run
    return int(run('lsof -u eastsun| wc -l', shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout.strip())


f0 = get_num_of_opened_files()
xs = Parallel(n_jobs=32, return_as='generator')(delayed(f)() for _ in range(32))
time.sleep(2)
f1 = get_num_of_opened_files()
print(f'Opened files: before {f0}, after {f1}, delta: {f1 - f0}', flush=True)
print(sum(xs))

Run the above py script will show that the joblib has opened about 3200 files when it is running.
 >> python lsof.py
 >> Opened files: before 388, after 3647, delta: 3259

It become even worse if I change the function f to a method of an instance with some attributes:
## lsof2.py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import time
import sys
import pandas as pd


class Tasker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = pd.Series([])

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(10)
        return 1.0

def get_num_of_opened_files() -> int:
    from subprocess import run
    return int(run('lsof -u eastsun| wc -l', shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout.strip())


tasker = Tasker()
f0 = get_num_of_opened_files()
xs = Parallel(n_jobs=32, return_as='generator')(delayed(tasker.run)() for _ in range(32))
time.sleep(2)
f1 = get_num_of_opened_files()
print(f'Opened files: before {f0}, after {f1}, delta: {f1 - f0}', flush=True)
print(sum(xs))

The opened files has doubled:
 >> python lsof2.py
 >> Opened files: before 399, after 6794, delta: 6395

It would open about 60,000 files If I running 10 programs like this, and the joblib will claim that:

UserWarning: A worker stopped while some jobs were given to the
executor. This can be caused by a too short worker timeout or by a
memory leak.

How to decrease the opened files by joblib? I have confirmed that:

The opened files will decreased to about 4 if I add prefer='threads' in Parallel. However I do need multi-processing rather than multi-threading.
Change the return_as parameter from generator to list has no effect.
About 60% of the opened files are .so file, which confused me very much.


It looks like it uses mmap to provide the backing store for the executor, and so a cursory look shows that opening many files is core to how this library functions (because it uses all of these to share states, it appears)? You may get a quicker response if you ask the developers directly if this is the case.

@metatoaster Hi,  I found that my previous question was misleading while I deep into the problem. I have edit the question.
